# Symfony 5.1.7 - unable to save data from disabled select box ChoiceType

Tags: symfony

I wanted to edit a form without changing a select box information. I managed to disable the select box but when I tried to save the form, I have an error

> Expected argument of type "string", "null" given at property path "action".

The form works fine with Create New (because the action ChoiceType is enabled). During edit, I disabled the action ChoiceType because I don't want the user to change it.

How can I save data from a disabled input?

_form.html.twig

```
    {{ form_start(form) }}
      {{ form_errors(form) }}
      {% if Update_req %}
        {{ form_row(form.action, {'attr': {'disabled': true}}) }}   
      {% else %}
        {{ form_row(form.action) }}
    {% endif %}
    {{ form_row(form.date) }}
    {{ form_row(form.amount) }}
    {{ form_row(form.remark) }}   
    <button class="btn btn-success">{{ button_label|default('Save') }}</button>
   {{ form_end(form) }}
```

edit.html.twig

```
{% block body %}
    {{ include('tithe/_form.html.twig', {'button_label': 'Update', 'Update_req': true}) }}    
    <hr />
    <a href="{{ path('tithe_index', {'bid': balance_id}) }}" class="btn btn-secondary">back to list</a>
    {{ include('tithe/_delete_form.html.twig') }}
{% endblock %}
```

TitheController.php

```
/**
     * @Route("/{id}/edit/", name="tithe_edit", methods={"GET","POST"})
     */
    public function edit(Request $request, Tithe $tithe, BalanceRepository $balanceRepository, SessionInterface $session): Response
    {

        $form = $this->createForm(TitheType::class, $tithe);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        $bid = $session->get('BID');
        $balance = $balanceRepository->find($bid);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            if ($tithe->getDate() > $balance->getDate()) {
                $balance->setDate($tithe->getDate());
            } // if ($tithe->getDate() > $balance->getDate())

            $prev_bal = $balance->getBalance();
            if ($tithe->getAction() == 'Withdrawal') {
                $balance->setBalance($prev_bal - $tithe->getAmount());
            } else { // Deposit
                $balance->setBalance($prev_bal + $tithe->getAmount());
            } // if ($tithe->getAction() == 'Withdrawal')

            $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->persist($tithe);
            $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->persist($balance);
            $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('balance_index');
        }

        return $this->render('tithe/edit.html.twig', [
            'tithe' => $tithe,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'balance_id' => $bid
        ]);
    }
```

TitheType.php

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('action', ChoiceType::class, [
                'required' => true,
                'label' => 'Action',
                'multiple' => false,
                'expanded' => false,
                'choices' => [
                    'Withdrawal' => 'Withdrawal',
                    'Deposit' => 'Deposit',
                ],
            ])
            ->add('date', DateType::class, [
                'years' => range(date('Y') - 1, date('Y'))
            ])
            ->add('amount')
            ->add('remark');
    }
```

Comment: disabled field won't post, use `readonly` instead.

Comment: @Norman. I works with text box but not with select box. The user can still change the item of the select box.

Comment: are you using select2?

Comment: @Norman. I am using in the form ChoiceType class as you can see in the TitheType.php file.

Answer (score 0):

As @Noman said, a disabled field is not post.

Maybe in edit, you shouldn't bind the 'action' to the form and display it as a single label. This way, the value in the entity wouldn't change at all.

Or maybe you could save the previous value of 'action' in a value and add it later in the if clause, this is dirtier imo :

```
public function edit(Request $request, Tithe $tithe, BalanceRepository $balanceRepository, SessionInterface $session): Response
{
    $action = $tithe->getAction();
    ...

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $tithe->setAction($action);
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Saving value in action $action = $tithe->getAction(); doesn't work. For the 1st solution, how can I assign the value (which is ChoiceType) to the new text box 'action'.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. According to Alexandre 1st proposition, I create a new form to edit the information.
I changed the 'action' ChoiceType to TextType as a readonly text.

```
public function change(Request $request, TitheRepository $titheRepo, BalanceRepository $balanceRepository, SessionInterface $session, $id)
    {
        $bid = $session->get('BID');
        $balance = $balanceRepository->find($bid);

        $tithe = $titheRepo->find($id);
        $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
            ->add('action', TextType::class)
            ->add('date', DateType::class)
            ->add('amount', TextType::class)
            ->add('remark', TextType::class)
            ->getForm();


        $form['action']->setData($tithe->getAction());
        $form['date']->setData($tithe->getDate());
        $form['amount']->setData($tithe->getAmount());
        $form['remark']->setData($tithe->getRemark());

        $form->handleRequest($request);
        ...
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $data = $form->getData();

            $tithe->setAction($data['action']);
            $tithe->setDate($data['date']);
            $tithe->setAmount($data['amount']);
            $tithe->setRemark($data['remark']);
            ...
        } // if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())

        return $this->render('tithe/change.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }
```

and change.html.twig

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Edit{% endblock %}
{% block body %}
    {{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_errors(form) }}
    {{ form_row(form.action, {'attr': {'readonly': true}}) }}   
    {{ form_row(form.date) }}
    {{ form_row(form.amount) }}
    {{ form_row(form.remark) }}   
    <button class="btn btn-success">{{ button_label|default('Save') }}</button>
    {{ form_end(form) }}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: You don't have to create another form for that, you could send the "$tithe" to the view and just display the 'action' value. Also, you need to add an option to your form to add or not the 'action' field in your form.